# Gl.VertexAttribPointer() does not work when specifying an Integer Offset but works when inputting null

Tags: c#, opengl

I am Trying to make a Game Engine in C# and OpenGL using OpenGL.NET. I have abstracted the Basic OpenGL Objects like VAO, VBO, etc. I Have a BufferLayout Class which specifies the Data present in the Vertex Buffer. The method in the VertexArray class that adds a buffer is this:

```cs
public void AddBuffer(uint index, ref VertexBuffer buffer)
{
    Bind();
    buffer.Bind();
    uint i = index;

    foreach (BufferElement element in buffer.Layout.Elements)
    {
        Gl.VertexAttribPointer(
            i++,
            element.GetComponentCount(),
            Globals.ShaderDataTypeToOpenGLBaseType(element.Type),
            element.Normalized,
            buffer.Layout.Stride,
            element.Offset
        );
    }
    m_Buffers.Add(buffer);
}
```

This method has 2 Overloads: One which takes an `IntPtr` as the Offset and another which takes in an `object`.
This is the overload which takes in an `object`. But for some reason, the `element.Offset` is not working as expected. As I am only using a positions attribute for this test, it works when I replace `element.Offset` with `null`.

Here is BufferLayout.cs

```cs
public enum ShaderDataType
{
    None,
    Float, Float2, Float3, Float4,
    Mat3, Mat4,
    Int, Int2, Int3, Int4,
}

public class BufferElement
{
    internal string Name;
    internal ShaderDataType Type;
    internal int Size;
    internal int Offset;
    internal bool Normalized;

    public BufferElement(ShaderDataType type, string name, bool normalized = false)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Size = Globals.ShaderDataTypeSize(type);
        Offset = 0;
        Normalized = normalized;
    }

    internal void SetOffset(int offset) => Offset = offset;

    public int GetComponentCount()
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case ShaderDataType.Float:      return 1;
            case ShaderDataType.Float2:     return 2;
            case ShaderDataType.Float3:     return 3;
            case ShaderDataType.Float4:     return 4;
            case ShaderDataType.Mat3:       return 3 * 3;
            case ShaderDataType.Mat4:       return 4 * 4;
            case ShaderDataType.Int:        return 1;
            case ShaderDataType.Int2:       return 2;
            case ShaderDataType.Int3:       return 3;
            case ShaderDataType.Int4:       return 4;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

internal sealed class BufferLayout
{
    public List<BufferElement> Elements { get; private set; }

    public int Stride { get; private set; }

    public BufferLayout(BufferElement[] e)
    {
        Elements = new List<BufferElement>();
        Elements.AddRange(e);
        CalculateOffsetsAndStride();
    }

    private void CalculateOffsetsAndStride()
    {
        int offset = 0;
        Stride = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Count; i++)
        {
            Elements[0].SetOffset(offset);
            offset += Elements[0].Size;
            Stride += Elements[0].Size;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload which takes an object is meant for compatibility profile [OpenGL contex](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and the object has to be an object containing the vertex array data.

If you want to set an offset, then you have to create an `IntPtr`. e.g:

```cs
var offset = new IntPtr(element.Offset);
Gl.VertexAttribPointer(
    i++,
    element.GetComponentCount(),
    Globals.ShaderDataTypeToOpenGLBaseType(element.Type),
    element.Normalized,
    buffer.Layout.Stride,
    offset
);
```

Note, the offset and the stride parameter have to be specified in bytes.